# Environment properties of EB not available for .NET Api

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, .net-6.0

I created a .NET windows platform application on EB with some env properties in the configuration. When I used the console built in AWS to check the env properties everything is fine, but when I deployed my .NET Api, there are no env properties available. I know there are no env properties available because I used Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables() function in my code to print them all and just print some default env properties, not the ones I setted.

The way I'm calling the env properties is with Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("");

For example I have the following keys:

firebase:projectId
firebase:private-key
mongo-db:connection-string
mongo-db:database-name

This are keys with sensitive data, so I don't think they should be public to the world.

I've tried to change the platform of the applicacion, I've tried instead of using environment properties reading it from appsettings.json but nothing is working.